# Client listens a incoming data from server with get JSON request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, get

I have a client gets JSON request that gets certain data from a server, as soon as something come in the server (server has a time interval of 10secs listening incoming data) the client gets the data.

Now the problem is all the data the client got are staying in a **queue**, they come out one by one after every time interval, so every time interval shows only one data.

I want every data came from the server should be shown independent on the time interval. Any help is appreciated!

```
function getRequest(i) {
        $.getJSON(
                '/nextdocument',
                function(data) {

                    console.log(data.documentID + data.description +
                                data.price + data.instanceId + data.errorMessage);
                }
        );
        setTimeout(function() {
            getRequest(i);
        }, 11000);

}
```

Comment: So create a function to get all new documents rather than the one you are using to just get the next document

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), which is just a general term for "live data fetching". This contains techniques like

- polling (which you are doing)
- "hold the line" (i forgot the proper term), where the server does not respond until something new arrives in the server, thus emulating a "push"
- using Flash to utilize it's streaming capabilities

you should also check out [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) for two-way "push" data transfer

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote:

> Thanks for advice, I have solved it by following code:
>
> ```
> function getRequest() {
>     $.ajax({
>         url: '/nextdocument',
>         type: 'GET',
>         async: true,
>         cache: false,
>         timeout: 11000, 
>         success: function(data) {
>             console.log(data.documentID + data.description +
>                         data.price + data.instanceId);
>             setTimeout(
>                     'getRequest()',
>                     1000
>             );
>
>             data["ok"] = data.ok;
>             data["errorMessage"] = data.errorMessage;
>             $.ajax(
>                     {
>                         url: "/customerdone",
>                         data: JSON.stringify(data),
>                         processData: false,
>                         type: 'POST',
>                         contentType: 'application/json'
>                     }
>             )
>             //no document if no read in
>             if (data.ok == "false") {
>                 console.log(data.errorMessage);
>             }
>         }
>     })
> }
> ```

Comment: ([Answered in a question edit and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).)